# System.AccessViolationException when trying to copy the last line of a Bitmap image

Tags: c#, memory, copy, marshalling, access-violation

I'm extracting rows of pixels from an image to an array of int, using Marshal.Copy. Everything works fine until I reach the last line of the image. If I try to extract it, I get a nice exception :

```
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Here is a little test case that reproduces the error. What am I doing wrong ?

```
[Test]
public void testMarshalCopy() {
    Bitmap image = new Bitmap("../../TestResources/barcode.jpg");

    int left = 0;
    int top = image.Height - 1;
    int width = image.Width;
    int height = 1;

    Rectangle zone = new Rectangle(left, top, width, height);
    BitmapData data = image.LockBits(zone, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, image.PixelFormat);

    IntPtr pointer = data.Scan0;
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];

    Marshal.Copy(pointer, pixels, 0, pixels.Length); // throws System.AccessViolationException

    image.UnlockBits(data);
}
```

Comment: What is your image pixel format?  Is each pixel  == `sizeof(int)`?

Comment: Fwiw, that's the first line.  Bitmaps are stored upside-down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image I was loading was using `Format24bppRgb` as pixel format. As Hans said, working with `Format32bppRgb` allows to work directly with `int[]` instead of `byte[]`.

I changed the pixel format to `Format32bppRgb` and now it works !

Comment: Normally you mark an answer and leave a comment rather then leaving another answer.

Comment: I think I know how SO works... There was no answer saying this, just a comment, so to make it visible I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your not taking your pixel format into account when your copying.

Look at this example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229672(v=vs.80).aspx

Notice they are coping a buffer of width * height * 3.

The image in this example is RGB format, one byte per color channel.

See this line here near the top:

```
PixelFormat pxf = PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb;
```

One more edit -

You should also be paying attention to the bitmap's Stride value.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.stride.aspx

Comment: Yes.  However, use Format32bppRgb so int[] is still usable.  24bpp is hard to deal with.  Stride doesn't matter here.

Comment: I agree, it just that way in the msdn example and understanding the concept of bitmap stride may be usefull to the poster, so I threw it in.

Answer (score 1):

The number of bytes in your locked bitmap zone depends on the image format, trying to extract more bytes will throw an Exception. To make things easier you can use a byte array, which will work with any image format but you have to adjust the multiplier - the example below assumes a 3 byte (24bpp) image format.

```
        int bytesNeeded =  zone.Width * zone.Height * 3; 
        byte[] pixels = new byte[bytesNeeded];

        Marshal.Copy(pointer, pixels, 0, pixels.Length); 
        image.UnlockBits(data);
```